# Как получить id нажатого элемента в LinearLayout

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Имеется 2 `Layout`'а.
На основной экран выводятся 5 картинок которые можно поскроллить горизонтально. Хочется чтобы можно было выбрать одну из них.
Пытаюсь получить id нажатого `ImageButton`. Но Такой способ не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно еще с этим справиться?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/large_visa_card_1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

и второй

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clickable = "true" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

И сама `Activity`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();

        LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        for (int i = 0;i<5;i++)
        {
            View view = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardsdialog, linLayout);
            linLayout.addView(view);
            ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), v.getId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тебе нужно воспользоваться методом **setTag()** для **ImageButton**

В цикле, где ты добавляешь элементы в **LinearLayout**, выставляй методом **setTag()** для **ImageButton** индекс элемента, потом в **onclickListener**'е берешь этот тег методом **getTag()**, приводишь к типу **int** и готово.

Comment: Спасибо! то что нужно.

Comment: Есть еще особенность, что "кнопки" нужно создавать программно) Иначе GetTag будет работать только для одной "нопки") Это так, если кто то еще столкнется с проблеммой такой)

Comment: что значит для одной кнопки? мне кажется что-то не то вы делаете

Comment: хз что не так, добавил всплывающее сообщение на каждую кнопку, в итоге выводится только у первой кнопки. Со значением для последней.

Comment: странно конечно

Comment: Извиняюсь. Вы правы. Попробовал заного, все отлично сработало.

Просто в строке ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); Нужно было указывать "item" вот так ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) item.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); что бы получать конкретный экземпляр.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.someImage);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
   assert(R.id.someImage == imageView.getId());
   switch(getDrawableId(imageView)) {
    case R.drawable.foo:
     imageView.setDrawableResource(R.drawable.bar);
     break;
    case R.drawable.bar:
    default:
     imageView.setDrawableResource(R.drawable.foo);

     break;
  }
});
```

Нашел код на [stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526585/imageview-drawable-id-in-android)

Хотя, я бы на твоем месте просто на каждый имедж вью повесил онклик листенер и по клику вызывал что нужно.

Comment: Дело в том, что их количество может увеличиваться по ходу работы программы. Их смогут добавить, или удалить.

Comment: И извиняюсь, немного не так наверное сформулировал... Нужен Индекс элемента. Знаю что может помочь метод indexOfChild(); но не могу его прикрутить :(